# Simple query not working after changing database collation

Tags: mariadb

I had a database whose collation was uneven using several different kinds in different tables and among different columns. So I changed the collation of all tables and columns to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. Now a simple query doesn't work. I'm entering this into phpmyadmin

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'abc@gmail.com'
```

`abc@gmail.com` does exist in the database but I don't get any result from the query. What do I do to fix this?

The charset of the database is `utf8mb4`

Comment: Are you sure that changing the collation is what caused your problem? If you change the collation back to whatever it was before, does your query start working?

Comment: Yes. It does start working after reverting back. The email field particularly was `utf8mb3_unicode_ci`

Comment: A server reboot seems to have fixed it. Although I did restart mariadb server after change. Weird.